# dnf upgrade problem

Tags: centos, upgrade, dnf

when issuing the command `dnf upgrade` on centos 8 I receive the following:

```
Error:
 Problem 1: package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-agent-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 and net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install both net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 and net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
 Problem 2: package net-snmp-gui-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-perl(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 and net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install both net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 and net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-gui-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
 Problem 3: problem with installed package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-agent-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 and net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install both net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 and net-snmp-agent-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64
  - package net-snmp-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 requires net-snmp-agent-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-10.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
 Problem 4: problem with installed package net-snmp-gui-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - package net-snmp-gui-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-perl(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 requires net-snmp-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-7.el8.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 and net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
  - cannot install both net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64 and net-snmp-libs-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64
  - package net-snmp-utils-1:5.8-10.el8.x86_64 requires net-snmp-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.8-10.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package net-snmp-utils-1:5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Any clue on what I can do about this issue without having to use `--allowerasing` and `--skip-broken` as I am trying to understand what the message means, but unfortunately I can't tell which package is causing this issue.

I also noticed this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum list installed | grep snmp

Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-MySQL:4.046:8010020191114030811:073fa5fe-0.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-SQLite:1.58:8010020191114033549:073fa5fe-0.x86_64
 Problem 3: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020191113222731:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64
net-snmp.x86_64                                    1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64                         1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
net-snmp-gui.x86_64                                1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
net-snmp-libs.x86_64                               1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
net-snmp-perl.x86_64                               1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
net-snmp-utils.x86_64                              1:5.8-7.el8.2                                     @okay
pcp-pmda-snmp.x86_64                               4.3.2-2.el8                                       @AppStream
snmptt.noarch                                      1.4-1.7                                           @@commandline
```

also this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep snmp
net-snmp-agent-libs-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
net-snmp-perl-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
net-snmp-utils-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
net-snmp-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
pcp-pmda-snmp-4.3.2-2.el8.x86_64
snmptt-1.4-1.7.noarch
net-snmp-libs-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
net-snmp-gui-5.8-7.el8.2.x86_64
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** 8th June 2020: I filed a bug on Redhat because I have a premium support, bug [#1773441](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1773441). Redhat is no longr building net-snmp-perl, so I think net-snmp-perl 1:5.8-12.el8_1.1 will be available soon.

I found the problem, it seems that net-snmp-perl-1:5.8-10.el8 doesn't exist for Centos 8, why installing net-snmp-perl, it downgrades these packages to 1:5.8-7.el8. Apparently it was a bad idea going with Centos 8 this time. There are many missing packages that I had to manually install, such as snmptt, any idea how one can request this package to become available for Centos 8

```
=======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Architecture                  Version                               Repository                        Size
=======================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
 net-snmp                                   x86_64                        1:5.8-10.el8                          AppStream                        353 k
 net-snmp-agent-libs                        x86_64                        1:5.8-10.el8                          AppStream                        751 k
 net-snmp-utils                             x86_64                        1:5.8-10.el8                          AppStream                        238 k
 net-snmp-libs                              x86_64                        1:5.8-10.el8                          BaseOS                           822 k
Removing dependent packages:
 net-snmp-perl                              x86_64                        1:5.8-7.el8.2                         @okay                            1.2 M

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  4 Packages
Remove   1 Package
```

Comment: Try filing a bug here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi